# Getting a photo of a place from Google Places Api

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to get photos of nearby locations using JSON in android as directed here: [Place Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqHiC.png.), and the path photo returns

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqHiC.png.): https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos null which is this image: [image: Image returned from image path]

This is the path I used for my attempt to get an image: [Image Path](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=YOUR_API_KEY)
.

This is my JSON structure: [image: JSON structure]

Is there something I should do before calling the image path or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you put your real API key?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using my my real API key. Please try it using your API, and tell me if does display.

Comment: If the server is unable to understand your request, it will return HTTP 400 status, which indicates an invalid request. The most common reasons why you might see an invalid request include:

The submitted photo reference was incorrectly specified.
Your request did not include either a maxwidth or maxheight parameter.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS This is how I called it: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY. Is there something you notice I did wrong? cause the Photo reference is the first one on my JSON structure I sent above

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS, I cannot find Google Picker  API but only these: Google Maps APIs

Google Maps Android API
Google Maps SDK for iOS
Google Maps JavaScript API
Google Places API for Android
Google Places API for iOS
Google Maps Roads API
Google Static Maps API
Google Street View Image API
Google Maps Embed API
Google Places API Web Service
Google Maps Geocoding API
Google Maps Directions API
Google Maps Distance Matrix API
Google Maps Geolocation API
Google Maps Elevation API
Google Maps Time Zone API

Comment: @Zack search photo in google developer library section search bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137748/discussion-between-zack-and-maharith-aditya-s-s).

Comment: My API_KEY for Google Places API for Android is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I Found a solution, all thanks to @MaharithAdityaSS. Basically I only needed to enable my Google Places API Web Service, as I only had Google Places API for Android only enabled. It now can display photos.