# Get a photo of a address using googlemaps

Tags: swift, google-maps

I want to try and get the image which is displayed when you look up an address on Google Maps like the one below and use it in my app. I can't find anything in my research except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712902/getting-a-photo-of-a-place-from-google-places-api) question on Stackoverflow which doesn't really solve my query. Does Google Maps have an API to access these images when you look up an address?  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps SDK for iOS allows you to use Google's Streetview in your app:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview?hl=de

There is also a Web API that you can use to request Streetview images for a certain location (and heading):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?hl=de

Both APIs expect coordinates as parameters so if you only have the address you might have to convert it to coordinates first.